# Mule http:inbound-endpoint get body of request

Tags: java, http, mule

```
<flow name="restTestFlow1" doc:name="restTestFlow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <logger message="#[message]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

How I can access to raw body in Mule?

Answer:

```
<flow name="carl_testFlow1" doc:name="carl_testFlow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <object-to-string-transformer />
    <logger message="#[message:payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>
</flow>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any of the following to read the body of the request.

```
<logger level="INFO" message="#[payload]" />
```

The following will print the payload as String

```
<logger level="INFO" message="#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" />
```

Hope this helps.